# Column name not populating on asp.net.cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have added to column to my db, 
When I try to configure it with frontend code I am not getting those two new columns,
,Although I could see System has generated columns which are in the table which I added to the db but the two new columns aren't present kindly advice what sort db approach are they performing here.
Note:
I am working on asp.net webforms

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? What is the database? Can you show us your code? How it is this being displayed in the front end?

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the DataSet, DataTable, or whatever else it is you're using as your DataSource. Visual Studio does not automatically look for changes in the database after you've added that information to your project. You need to give more information for us to help you further.